# Switching from GUI to Command Prompt in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, cmd

My professor assigned a project where a simulation is ran through a GUI. To edit it, we need to create a "New" menu item. We haven't learned how to get data from a GUI, and our book does not cover it at all.

What I'm trying to do, is when the "New" command is hit, focus gets shifted back to the CMD prompt, where System.out. starts working again and prompts the user for input.

However, when I try to implement this, my program crashes. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're keeping the reference to your newly created GUI.  As far as I remember, Java will garbage collect the FoxGui object (as well as any other object) if there are no references to that object.  Try creating a global variable to store the reference to your newly created FoxGui object.  Something like...

```
FoxGui MyGUIRef;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{ 
    System.out.println("Item: " + event.getActionCommand());

    // File Menu Controls
   if (event.getActionCommand().equals("New"))
   {
       MyGUIRef = runNew();
   }
}

//Now returns a reference to FoxGui
private FoxGui runNew()
{
     return new FoxGui(....)
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I have absolutely no idea...  I could have sworn it was in the question before though.  After looking at other answers I think it may have been in my mind after seeing 'fox' in the answer by Eric.  The point of references/garbage collection thankfully doesn't lose its meaning though!:)

Comment: Ok, I see it now ("new FoxGui(depth, width, fox, rabbit);"); I guess that's one hazard of people adding answers instead of editing the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the System.out in a terminal (non Java) window?  If so, I think this would be much harder than you'd think.

I'd be tempted to redirect the System.in / System.out to a JTextPane on the GUI (That way, it would be much easier to change the focus etc.  I think you need to try and explain what you're doing a little better in your question and perhaps post a stack trace when your program crashes.

Anyway, to do something when the "new" menu item is clicked you'd need to do:

```
menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // Code here to be performed when the item is clicked
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You know what? I found a real simple solution, JOptionPane. I just needed to find a good example. It'll work fine for what I want. Thanks for all the help. I'll checkmark everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is very late answer, but anywhere...

There is only one way to do exactly what you want.

1. First you need to remember to run you project from CMD by java -jar jarname.jar
2. Catch click action and perform system.in

Information:

It is the only solution, because GUI never give focus to CMD, but if GUI runned from CMD you can use easily System.in.

Regards, Greg